# Why hasn't Vijay Mallya been extradited yet?

Tags: fraud, india, money-laundering

Vijay Mallya is an Indian businessman at present fighting extradition from the UK. Mallya, who owes 17 Indian banks an estimated Rs 9,000 crore.

> Mallya inherited UB Spirits, known for the Kingfisher beer brand, from his father and turned it around into India’s biggest spirits maker. He became the chairman of UB Group at the age of 28. However, most other group businesses were not as successful, Kingfisher Airlines being the biggest failure

[Kingfisher scam](https://camonk.com/blog/the-mallya-case-kingfisher-scam)

So what happened to his trial? Why the UK did not return him finally to India? Why has this case become cold after 2019?

Comment: are you looking for us to google this for you?  https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/topic/vijay-mallya-case

Comment: @TigerGuy it's a recent development in terms of total money laundering committed by them.  why aren't they behind the bar? what is the reason behind keeping them in the UK? by which act UK did not hand him over to India?

Comment: @TigerGuy clearly [FOE](https://byjus.com/free-ias-prep/fugitive-economic-offenders-act/) overlaps with Right to life action eg. section 21 so anyone can go abroad if he/she is accused under FEO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why the UK did not return him finally to India?**

> ...in October 2020 the Indian government was notified that Mallya could not be currently extradited due to an unspecified "*confidential legal matter*" [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijay_Mallya) and [here](https://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/crime/091020/mallyas-extradition-from-britain-not-possible-india-told.html)

Comment: See also [this article, published earlier today:](https://www.news18.com/news/india/where-are-vijay-mallya-and-nirav-modi-now-a-news18-primer-as-india-plans-to-raise-pending-extraditions-during-boris-johnson-visit-5010295.html) "The UK Home Office has so far only confirmed on background that a confidential legal process remains ongoing before the extradition request, signed by the Home Secretary on February 3, 2019, can be certified and executed."